# In SwiftUI how to do a paginated infinite scrolling `List` from a Core Data fetch request

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

Is this the right way to do a paginated infinite scrolling `List` from a Core Data fetch request? The solution below seems to work on iOS 17 and Mac Catalyst 16.

I'm asking because the solution seems odd to me. I could only get this to work with `fetchLimit` hoisted to the parent of the `View` that contains the `List` even though `fetchLimit` is logically `@State` that belongs with the `View` that directly contains the `List`. That is because I can't think of a way to initialize the `@FetchRequest` state except with a value passed to init, rather than with a binding.

This code depends on a core data entity named `Item` that has 2 `Date` attributes named `date` and `timestamp` and a 3rd `Integer 32` attribute named `value`.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FetchQueryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var fetchOffset = 10

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            FetchQueryListView(initialFetchLimit: fetchOffset, fetchLimitBinding: $fetchOffset)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: { addItem(viewContext) }) {
                            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: { add50Items(viewContext) } ) {
                            Label("Add 50 Items", systemImage: "plus.square.on.square")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
    
struct FetchQueryListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @Binding var fetchLimitBinding : Int
    
    init(initialFetchLimit: Int, fetchLimitBinding: Binding<Int>) {
        self._fetchLimitBinding = fetchLimitBinding

        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: false)
        ]
        request.fetchLimit = initialFetchLimit
        _items = FetchRequest<Item>(fetchRequest: request)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: item)) {
                    Text("\(item.timestamp!, formatter: datetimeFormatter) - \(item.value)")
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            
            Text("Bottom")
              .onAppear {
                  fetchLimitBinding = fetchLimitBinding + 10
              }
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            saveContext(viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct SectionedFetchQueryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var fetchOffset = 10

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SectionedFetchQueryListView(initialFetchLimit: fetchOffset, fetchLimitBinding: $fetchOffset)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: { addItem(viewContext) }) {
                            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: { add50Items(viewContext) } ) {
                            Label("Add 50 Items", systemImage: "plus.square.on.square")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct SectionedFetchQueryListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @SectionedFetchRequest
    private var items: SectionedFetchResults<Date, Item>
    
    @Binding var fetchLimitBinding : Int
    
    init(initialFetchLimit: Int, fetchLimitBinding: Binding<Int>) {
        self._fetchLimitBinding = fetchLimitBinding

        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: false)
        ]
        request.fetchLimit = initialFetchLimit
        _items = SectionedFetchRequest<Date, Item>(fetchRequest: request, sectionIdentifier: \.date!)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { section in
                Section("\(section.id, formatter: dateFormatter)") {
                    ForEach(section) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: item)) {
                            Text("\(item.timestamp!, formatter: timeFormatter) - \(item.value)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Text("Bottom")
              .onAppear {
                  fetchLimitBinding = fetchLimitBinding + 10
              }
        }
    }
}

private func stripTime(_ timestamp: Date?) -> Date {
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: timestamp!)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    return date!
}

private func addItem(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    withAnimation {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
        newItem.date = stripTime(newItem.timestamp)
        newItem.value = Int32(Int.random(in: 1..<1000))
        saveContext(viewContext)
    }
}

private func add50Items(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    withAnimation {
        for _ in 0..<50 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            newItem.date = stripTime(newItem.timestamp)
            newItem.value = Int32.random(in: 0..<1000)
        }
        saveContext(viewContext)
    }
}
private func saveContext(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if viewContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

let datetimeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    return formatter
}()

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    return formatter
}()

let timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    return formatter
}()

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @State private var selectedDate: Date

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        self._selectedDate = State(initialValue: item.timestamp!)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            DatePicker("Time", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            LabeledContent("Value") {
                TextField("Value", value: $item.value, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit")
        .onDisappear {
            item.timestamp = selectedDate
            item.date = stripTime(item.timestamp)
            try? viewContext.save()
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestPagination")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}

@main
struct TestPaginationApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                FetchQueryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("FetchQuery")
                    }
                SectionedFetchQueryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("SectionedFetch")
                    }
                }
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```