# Paginated infinite scrolling for a `ScrollView` containing a `VStack` on Mac Catalyst

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I am trying to find a way to implement paginated infinite scrolling for a `ScrollView` containing a `VStack` from a Core Data fetch request. The solution below seems to work on iOS 17 and 16.4, but not on Mac Catalyst 16. Unfortunately I can't use a List [I think I have a working solution here for Lists.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768199/in-swiftui-how-to-do-a-paginated-infinite-scrolling-list-from-a-core-data-fetc) The code below is based on a great [StackOverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60569935/4087694). Can anyone help me to get this working on Mac Catalyst? Thank you!

This code depends on a core data entity named Item that has 2 Date attributes named date and timestamp and a 3rd Integer 32 attribute named value.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct PositionData: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let center: Anchor<CGPoint>
}

struct Positions: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [PositionData] = []
    static func reduce(value: inout [PositionData], nextValue: () -> [PositionData]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct ScrollGeomSectionedFetchQueryView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var fetchLimit = 10

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SectionedFetchQueryScrollVStackGeomView(initialFetchLimit: fetchLimit, fetchLimitBinding: $fetchLimit)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: { addItem(viewContext) }) {
                            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: { add50Items(viewContext) } ) {
                            Label("Add 50 Items", systemImage: "plus.square.on.square")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct SectionedFetchQueryScrollVStackGeomView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @SectionedFetchRequest
    private var items: SectionedFetchResults<Date, Item>
    
    @Binding var fetchLimitBinding : Int
    @State var flag = false
    
    init(initialFetchLimit: Int, fetchLimitBinding: Binding<Int>) {
        self._fetchLimitBinding = fetchLimitBinding

        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: false)
        ]
        request.fetchLimit = initialFetchLimit
        _items = SectionedFetchRequest<Date, Item>(fetchRequest: request, sectionIdentifier: \.date!)
    }

    func getPosition(proxy: GeometryProxy, tag: Int, preferences: [PositionData])->CGPoint {
        let p = preferences.filter({ (p) -> Bool in
            p.id == tag
            })
        if p.isEmpty { return .zero }
        
        if proxy.size.height - proxy[p[0].center].y > 0 && flag == false {
            self.flag.toggle()
            fetchLimitBinding = fetchLimitBinding + 10
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
                self.flag.toggle()
            }

            print("fetch")
        }
        return .zero
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView([.vertical]) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        EmptyView().id("top")
                        
                        ForEach(items) { section in
                            ForEach(section) { item in
                                NavigationLink(destination: EditItemView(item: item)) {
                                    Text("\(item.timestamp!, formatter: timeFormatter) - \(item.value)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Rectangle().tag(items.count).frame(height: 0).anchorPreference(key: Positions.self, value: .center) { (anchor) in
                            [PositionData(id: self.items.count, center: anchor)]
                        }.id(items.count)
                    }
                }
            }
            .backgroundPreferenceValue(Positions.self) { (preferences) in
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 0, height: 0).position(self.getPosition(proxy: proxy, tag: self.items.count, preferences: preferences))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private func stripTime(_ timestamp: Date?) -> Date {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: timestamp!)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    return date!
}

private func addItem(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    withAnimation {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
        newItem.date = stripTime(newItem.timestamp)
        newItem.value = Int32(Int.random(in: 1..<1000))
        saveContext(viewContext)
    }
}

private func add50Items(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    withAnimation {
        for _ in 0..<50 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            newItem.date = stripTime(newItem.timestamp)
            newItem.value = Int32.random(in: 0..<1000)
        }
        saveContext(viewContext)
    }
}

private func saveContext(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if viewContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

let datetimeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    return formatter
}()

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    return formatter
}()

let timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    return formatter
}()

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @State private var selectedDate: Date

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        self._selectedDate = State(initialValue: item.timestamp!)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
            DatePicker("Time", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            LabeledContent("Value") {
                TextField("Value", value: $item.value, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit")
        .onDisappear {
            item.timestamp = selectedDate
            item.date = stripTime(item.timestamp)
            try? viewContext.save()
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestPagination")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}

@main
struct TestPaginationApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                ScrollGeomSectionedFetchQueryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("ScrollGeom SectionedFetch")
                    }
            }
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this can be of any help, but I do have a working Infinite Carousel on Mac Catalyst 16. It may need a bit of adjustments based on your needs, but I hope to put you in the right direction or give you a hint.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct LoopingScrollView<Content: View, Items: RandomAccessCollection>: View where Items.Element: Identifiable {
    
    /// Customization properties
    var width: CGFloat
    var spacing: CGFloat
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var items: Items
    @ViewBuilder var content: (Items.Element) -> Content
    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let size = geometry.size
            /// Safety check
            let repeatingCount = width > 0 ? Int((size.width / width).rounded()) + 1 : 1
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: spacing) {
                    
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        content(item)
                            .frame(width: width)
                    } //: LOOP
                    
                    ForEach(0..<repeatingCount, id: \.self) { index in
                        let item = Array(items)[index % items.count]
                        content(item)
                            .frame(width: width)
                        
                    } //: LOOP
                } //: LazyHStack
                .background(
                    ScrollViewHelper(width: width,
                                     spacing: spacing,
                                     itemCount: items.count,
                                     repeatingCount: repeatingCount
                                    )
                )
                
            } //: SCROLL
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            
        } //: GEOMETRY
    }
}

fileprivate struct ScrollViewHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var width: CGFloat
    var spacing: CGFloat
    var itemCount: Int
    var repeatingCount: Int
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(width: width,
                           spacing: spacing,
                           itemCount: itemCount,
                           repeatingCount: repeatingCount
        )
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return .init()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.06) {
            if let scrollview = uiView.superview?.superview?.superview as? UIScrollView,
               !context.coordinator.isAdded {
                scrollview.delegate = context.coordinator
                context.coordinator.isAdded = true
            }
        }
        
        context.coordinator.width = width
        context.coordinator.spacing = spacing
        context.coordinator.itemCount = itemCount
        context.coordinator.repeatingCount = repeatingCount
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
        var width: CGFloat
        var spacing: CGFloat
        var itemCount: Int
        var repeatingCount: Int
        ///Tells us whether the delegate is added or not
        var isAdded: Bool = false
        
        init(width: CGFloat, spacing: CGFloat, itemCount: Int, repeatingCount: Int) {
            self.width = width
            self.spacing = spacing
            self.itemCount = itemCount
            self.repeatingCount = repeatingCount
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            guard itemCount > 0 else { return }
            let minX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
            let mainContentSize = CGFloat(itemCount) * width
            let spacingSize = CGFloat(itemCount) * spacing
            
            if minX > (mainContentSize + spacingSize) {
                scrollView.contentOffset.x -= (mainContentSize + spacingSize)
            }
            
            if minX < 0 {
                scrollView.contentOffset.x += (mainContentSize + spacingSize)
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

It lacks the paging behaviour since this was first written using the new iOS 17 APIs, just commenting it made it work on Mac Catalyst though.
You can use this Infinte Carousel Like this:

```
let width: CGFloat = 150
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geom in
                
                let size = geom.size
                
                LoopingScrollView(width: size.width, spacing: 0, items: items) { item in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(item.color.gradient)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                }
                //.contentMargins(.horizontal, 15, for: .scrollContent)
                //.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging) // <-- Only works on iOS 17+
            }
            .frame(height: width)
            
        } //: VSTACK
        .padding(.vertical, 15)
    } //: ScrollView
    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
```

The Item struct just contains an ID and a color, you can use any Identifiable object you want. For anyone wanting a paging behaviour on iOS 17+ just uncomment the `.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)` line.
This is how it looks: [image: Infinite Loop Scroll View]

Let me know if it was of any help.
All credits for this solution goes to YouTuber [kavsoft](https://youtube.com/@Kavsoft?si=jeVfePRGX60HXXYE) from who I learnt and keep learning a lot. But at least I saved someone the task of copying it again from his video.

Comment: Here is a link to the YouTube video for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyuo59840qs

If you are Kavsoft disregard but if not you really should give credit to original authors. Especially when you are posting verbatim the code written by someone else and that code is behind a paywall.

Comment: Indeed, I got It from kavsoft. I watch all his vidéos and have learnt a lot from him. I follow his tutorials step by step and have a lot of his projects in my GitHub repository here: https://github.com/MatHeartGaming/coolStuff_with_SwiftUI. But we all learn from some source right? And not everyone has the patience to do what I do. I'll give credits to him now, because the code Is the same, and you're right on that.

Comment: @wshamp what I did here though, was to be sure it worked on Mac catalyst too and removed incompatible stuff from it.